# Javascript function not getting called from typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angular, angular2-template

I have JSAngular2Demo.js in apps folder which contains a simple function :-

```
function sample()
{
    alert("sample");

}
```

I want to call this function from apps.component.ts

For this:-

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import "app/JSAngular2Demo.js";

declare function sample(): any;
@Component({ selector: "my-app", templateUrl:"app/UIAngular.html" })
export class AppComponent {
    strWelcomeMessage: string = "Welcome Sagar";
    constructor() {
        sample.prototype.sample();
    }
}
```

But this function is not getting called.

What can be the possible reason?

Comment: Why aren't you using Typescript?

Answer (score 1):

Export Your function in `JSAngular2Demo.js` like:-

```
   module.exports = {
        sample: function() {

           alert("sample");
        }

    }
```

`apps.component.ts`

```
import {sample} from './JSAngular2Demo';


    @Component({ selector: "my-app", templateUrl:"app/UIAngular.html" })
    export class AppComponent {
        strWelcomeMessage: string = "Welcome Sagar";
        constructor() {
          sample();
        }
    }
```

And Add `"allowJs": true,` to `tsconfig.json` file to allow js files under `compilerOptions`

Comment: import {sample} from './JSAngular2Demo'; is not working

Comment: Have you tried adding a reference of `JsAngularDemo.js` in `Index.html` ?

Comment: `import ` statement will work if you add `allowJs:true` in tsconfig file under `compilerOptions`